Testing passport.js login with selenium in CI fashion
I have a set of existing selenium (Selenium Webdriver 4, python) tests for a website that will henceforth be authenticated with passsport.js google oauth2. I want to continue automating the end-to-end workflow starting with the browser launch, so I need to get through the Passport auth in these tests.
On my local machine, I have found that manually authenticating in Chrome, then telling Chromedriver to use my Chrome profile to login:
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=<abs path to chrome user data>')
options.add_argument('--profile-name=Default')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

However in CI no such directory is available.
Is there an existing solution to authenticate in a CI pipeline? I am currently using CircleCI but open to changing that.
